# where is the fs/proc/proc.c in Linux Kernel source

Tags: linux, procfs

in Linux kernel source code, there are below words in fs/proc/Makefile

`obj-y   += proc.o`

but where is the fs/proc/proc.c file?

find the file in Linux source code, but not found.

Comment: There is no `proc.c`.  If I recall correctly, `proc.o` is built from the separate object files `inode.o`, `root.o`, etc, using `ld -r` which effectively combines many object files into one.  You could confirm by actually building it using `make V=1` to show all the commands that are run, or try to trace through Linux's very long and complex Makefile setup.  I suspect it's somewhere in [Makefile.build](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/Makefile.build) from one of the pattern rules using `%.o`.

Comment: @NateEldredge in [kbuild/Makefiles](https://docs.kernel.org/kbuild/makefiles.html#goal-definitions) said: "obj-y += foo.o

This tells kbuild that there is one object in that directory, named foo.o. foo.o will be built from foo.c or foo.S."               then maybe have some other Hidden rules?